# Event App Secret Key

Tags: facebook, wordpress, secret-key

How do I find my standard Facebook Event App Secret Key?
I need it for using a Facebook Event Widget in Wordpress

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps - the app secret is in the settings for each app

Comment: But I don't find the standard Event App there!

Comment: But you don't own the 'Event' app provided by Facebook so you wouldn't have access to make API calls on behalf of that app - it doesn't make sense to need that app secret, you should be using an app you created or administer (assuming what you're doing needs the app secret)

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a secret key for an application that you created yourself.